# How to reference mysql config file in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, configuration, phpmyadmin

I have been searching the web and all over stackoverflow, but yet couldn't find my answers.

My client has created an online mysql database with phpmyadmin installed.
I use a url like (http://domainName.com/folder1/index.php) to access the database tables and settings.

Now my problems are:

1. It's mentioned in the documentation of phpmyadmin that I should manually create a folder config in the phpMyAdmin directory. How can I do this exactly when the database is hosted online?
2. After getting to do number 1, I would want to place the config file in that folder and reference the database's username and password in my application's php files. I'm confused about the url I should include?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Use FTP 2) Use FTP, server name in config file should usually be `localhost`, username and password depend on your host's settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this...

1. FTP to the PHPMyAdmin directory on the web server.  If you need an FTP get FileZilla.
2. Copy/Rename your local copy of "config.sample.inc.php" to "config.inc.php"
3. Edit the "config.inc.php" file by finding the line that starts with...

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '';
   ```

   and change it to have the network address of the database.

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';//127.0.0.1 is just localhost IPv4
   ```
4. Save and upload the copied/renamed file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Concerning "FTP to the PHPMyAdmin directory on the web server", when I check my settings on PHPMyAdmin, it says that "There are no configured servers". Do I need to set one up? Also about the FTP thing, do I just replace the http in the database's url with FTP, or do I have to set sth up?

Comment: When I FTP the server, I don't see any folders. Just the php files of my application.

Comment: You probably need a privileged account (e.g. root) to access the phpMyAdmin files, which you probably don't have if the site is on a shared server. You can upload your own copy of phpMyAdmin to the directory that you do have FTP access to and go from there.

Comment: If it says "There are no configured servers" then you'll probably need to uncomment the block of configuration lines for at least 1 server or just play with the configuration a bit.  I hope this is constructive... you can find a bit more info here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install